# jQuery validation plugin show div on success

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, validation

I am using the jQuery validation plugin for one of my forms. On submit (and providing all the validation rules are met) I want to show a thank you message using ajax/hidden div, rather than page refresh. However, I can't seem to get this to work (and am clearly using the wrong code!)

Can someone please point me in the right direction of how to get this to work?

I am using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
                $("#myForm").validate({
                    rules: {
                        firstname: {required: true},
                        lastname: {required: true},
                        email: {required: true, email:true},
                        mobile: {required: true},
                        landline: {required: false},
                        comments: {required: true},
                        SUBMIT: "required SUBMIT",
                        success: function() {$('#thankyou1').slideDown("slow")}
                    },
                });
            });
    </script>   

    <form action="bin/contact.php" method="post" id="myForm">...</form>
    <div id="thankyou1">Thank you for contacting us we will be in touch shortly!</div>
```

Comment: Consider creating a jsFiddle. We might be able to help and "debug" ..

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form using ajax by adding the following code in `submitHandler` function of **jQuery Validator**:

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
         var valuesToSubmit = $(form).serialize();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            data: valuesToSubmit,
            dataType: "JSON"
          }).done(successFn).fail(errorFn);
        return false; // prevents the default form submit
       }

var successFn = function (json) {
   /* your success actions*/
};

var errorFn = function (json) {
   /* your error actions*/
};
```